# Create new list out of two lists via multiplication. Python

Tags: python, python-itertools, matrix-multiplication, cartesian-product

Good morning!

I'm trying to generate a new list out of two lists, by using multiplication operation.
Below I show you step by step what I did:

```
import itertools
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Parameter_list=[]

Parameter=[range(0,2,1),range(0,2,1)]
Parameter_list=list(itertools.product(*Parameter))
print(Parameter_list)

[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Then I deleted the first value, which is basically the null matrix:

```
del Parameter_list[0]
print(Parameter_list)
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

I proceeded by creating the two paramter list:

```
Parameter_A=[range(1,2,1),range(3,6,2),range(10,20,10)]
Parameter_A=list(itertools.product(*Parameter_A))

Parameter_B=[range(0,2,1),range(4,6,2),range(10,20,10)]
Parameter_B=list(itertools.product(*Parameter_B))

print(Parameter_A)
print(Parameter_B)

[(1, 3, 10), (1, 5, 10)]
[(0, 4, 10), (1, 4, 10)]
```

And combined the lists:

```
comb=list(product(Parameter_A,Parameter_B))
print(comb)

[((1, 3, 10), (0, 4, 10)),
 ((1, 3, 10), (1, 4, 10)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (0, 4, 10)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (1, 4, 10))]
```

Until here no prob. But now I'm struggling to create a new list from multiplying the **Parameter List** with the **comb list**. The desired output is the following:

```
[((0, 0, 0), (0, 4, 10)),
 ((0, 0, 0), (1, 4, 10)), 
 ((0, 0, 0), (0, 4, 10)), 
 ((0, 0, 0), (1, 4, 10)),
 ((1, 3, 10), (0, 0, 0)),
 ((1, 3, 10), (0, 0, 0)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (0, 0, 0)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (0, 0, 0)),
 ((1, 3, 10), (0, 4, 10)),
 ((1, 3, 10), (1, 4, 10)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (0, 4, 10)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (1, 4, 10))]
```

Can someone help me? Many thanks!

Comment: I've read this twice and I just don't have the faintest idea what you're trying to do. I have no idea where `(0, 0, 0)` is coming from.

Comment: Parameter list is:
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]

When the parameter list is (0,1) you get zeros in Parameter A.
When the parameter list is (1,0) you get zeros in Parameter B.
When the parameter list is (1,0) you get no zeros and basically just the comb matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with lists instead of with a numpy array is not the most convenient choice. That said, it's still something you can do with a one-liner.

```
prod = [tuple(i if j != 0 else (0,) * len(i) for i, j in zip(comb_items, bool_items)) 
        for comb_items, bool_items in itertools.product(comb, Parameter_list)]

>>> prod
[((0, 0, 0),  (0, 4, 10)), 
 ((1, 3, 10), (0, 0, 0)), 
 ((1, 3, 10), (0, 4, 10)), 
 ((0, 0, 0),  (1, 4, 10)), 
 ((1, 3, 10), (0, 0, 0)), 
 ((1, 3, 10), (1, 4, 10)), 
 ((0, 0, 0),  (0, 4, 10)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (0, 0, 0)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (0, 4, 10)), 
 ((0, 0, 0),  (1, 4, 10)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (0, 0, 0)), 
 ((1, 5, 10), (1, 4, 10))]
```

I am assuming that the order of the outputs isn't critical and that the `Parameter_list` will always be booleans. Both of these things can be pretty easily changed if needed.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed. I will now check what bool_items mean within your code!